# Rundeck Key shared between different projects

Tags: rundeck

we have different projects and in each project there are different jobs.
To simplify the example, let's say we have project PRG_A and project PRG_B.
The user USER_1 has full permission on the PRG_A project and on the PRG_B project.
The user USER_2 has job execution permissions on the PRG_A project and full permission on the PRG_B project.

At this moment, the user USER_2, having the permissions to execute the jobs in the PRG_A project, is also able to see (the name and the path) the keys of the PRG_A project.
Our problem is that user USER_2 can create jobs on the PRG_B project using the PRG_A project keys.
This could be a real problem because he can create a job in PRG_B performing the echo command of the PRG_A key.

How should I configure the ACLs to ensure that the PRG_B project jobs can only use the PRG_B project keys and not the keys of other projects?

Thank you so much for your support

We tried different ACL configuration, but the key are visible

Answer (score 0):

As long as USER_2 has access to the keys of both projects, it will be able to access them from job secure options (even if you define the keys at the project level, like [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/history/3_4_x/version-3.4.0.html#project-based-acls-for-key-storage-enterprise)).

The best approach, in that case, is to create specific keys for that user like [this](https://kcaps.medium.com/rundeck-key-storage-acl-grant-access-to-path-27da34345220) example (or define separate users with specific rights, that would be ideal).